# How to "numpify" python nested list at creation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-lists, numpy-ndarray

my runtime is killing me because I don't understand how to take advantage of numpy arrays. My code now might look nonsensical but it's doing exactly what I want (l k-by-80000 arrays, but 2000 of those), except it takes way too long. It's really just a massive nested-nested-nested list made of random normal unit vectors. Currently, after the code listed (but inside the for loop, just at the first indent level) I work with tables in l_tables and I convert with numpy.array(listname), but there has to be a way to initialize these things directly as numpy arrays?

l and k are small-ish ints, for this purpose let l = k = 4

I've tried lots of versions of numpy.concatenate and numpy.arange, also checked out numpy.append(M, a), looked at examples too but I can't figure out how to get it to do exactly what I'm attempting

```
for z in range(1, 2001):
    l_tables = []
    for a in range(l):
        table = []
        for i in range(k):
            row = []
            for j in range(80000):
                result = numpy.random.normal(0, 1)
                row.append(result)
            table.append(row)
        l_tables.append(table)
```

## lots more code after this, unincluded

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation of your question is that you simply want a three-dimensional numpy array of normal distributed values. You can create this by specifying the size in the random normal command:

```
import numpy as np

l = 4
k = 4
j = 80000
l_tables = np.random.normal(0, 1, size = [l, k, j])
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Feeling very silly now. Question - how would I access each individual dimension? For example, let's say I had j = 2 and l = 3, so that l_tables looked like this: [[[][][][]] [[][][][]] [[][][][]]]  where each [] is 1x2. How do I access each [[][][][]] ? In traditional python I would just do "for row in l_tables" but I played around with it here and it gave me each individual numerical entry

Comment: You can use the numpy array syntax to select the elements and dimensions you want. The colon operator lets you select all elements in a given dimension. Try this simple example (you'll have to re-organize the code):
`import numpy as np

l = 2
k = 3
j = 4
l_tables = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[l, k, j])

print(l_tables)
print('')
# print k x j  planar array for the first element of l
print(l_tables[0, :, :])
print('')
# print l x j planar array for the third element of k
print(l_tables[:, 2, :])
print('')
# print the j values for first l and first k
print(l_tables[0, 0, :])`

Answer (score 0):

you have
2000 l_tables
l tables
k rows
80000 rows in each item

you can get it like this. but it will probably gonna take lots of memory

```py
l=4
k=4
np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(2000,l,k,80000))
```